# Pass input query parameter for lambda from AWS event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-event-bridge

Scenario: I have created single serverless lambda. No as per my requirement I need to have three different scheduler for same lambda with three different input parameter.

1. cron(0 12 ? * THU-SUN *) this trigger need to pass parameter as CAR
2. cron(0 13 ? * THU-SUN *) this trigger need to pass parameter as TRUCK
3. cron(0 14 ? * THU-SUN *) this trigger need to pass parameter as BIKE

Can someone had this scenario prior. If someone can help me on this it would be great help.

What i did:
I create three different event rule with different parameter. But when it get trigger i am having exception as below:
**InvalidRequestEventException**:The incoming event is not valid request from amazon API gateway or an Application load balancer